# SELECT with two foreign keys to one primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

1) "Folders", two columns, `FolderID (PrimaryKey)` and `FolderName (varchar, uniq)`;

2) "Images", three columns, `ID (Pr.Key)`, `SrcFolderID` and `DestFolderID` (both are foreign keys to Folders.FolderID).

How to make a select query which will return three columns:
`Images.ID`, `SrcFolderName` and `DestFolderName`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It works the same as if you had one foreign key to one primary key. Hopefully you can figure it out from here.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query-

```
SELECT img.id AS Image_Id, fld1.foldername AS Source_foldername,fld2.foldername AS Dest_foldername 
FROM images AS img 
LEFT JOIN folders AS fld1 ON fld1.id=img.srcfolderid 
LEFT JOIN folders AS fld2 ON fld2.id=img.destfolderid;
```

Note: You can add your other conditions also as per requirement.

Comment: Than you so much, this makes a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `as` to use different name for each joined table(or just add the name after the table name):

```
JOIN RIGHT folders destination_folder ON...
```

For more information look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp